# Unity: Firebase Realtime Database - OrderByChild does not work

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase Realtime Database in Unity for store users with scores. Structure:

```
Users
  2673g4fyuef6tw34
    BestScore: 5
    Name: "Test1"
  d2y3gferfhjy4gff
    BestScore: 0
    Name: "Test2"
  237dyg2fhkalskjr
    BestScore: 10
    Name: "Test3"
```

My query:

```cs
var taskResult = await FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
                .GetReference("Users")
                .OrderByChild("BestScore")
                .LimitToLast(20)
                .GetValueAsync()
                .ContinueWith(task => task);

RenderData(taskResult);
```

And my handler:

```cs
private void RenderData(Task<DataSnapshot> task)
{
    var snapshot = task.Result;

    foreach (var childSnapshot in snapshot.Children)
    {
        Debug.Log("Score: " + childSnapshot.Child("BestScore").Value);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Score: 5
Score: 0
Score: 10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try `LimitToLast()` before `OrderByChild()`?

Comment: Also, to reassure you a bit, your code looks perfectly reasonable and should function the way you've written it. [@puff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103) might have some insight into it when he's next online.

Comment: @samthecodingman Yes, as it turned out this is a firebase bug in Unity.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a firebase error in Unity Editor. 
Everything works on the phone (IOS, Android).